# Fastest way to parse arguments from standard input

Tags: c++, cin

Suppose you receive information from the standard input that's formatted in the following way:

```
1 2 3 #3 John Tee #2
4 2 1 @1 Tree Bee #9

<int><int><int><char followed by int><string><string><char followed by int>
```

What's the fastest way to extract this information for use in a program?  Also, suppose you wanted to check that the 4th and 7th arguments contained only a '#' followed by a number (and exit otherwise), or you wanted to check that a line doesn't end early, as in:

```
1 4 2 #4 John
```

How can you do this in c++ in the cleanest, most efficient way?

Comment: Could you give some more details about the *format* of the input, not only an example? What do the fields mean and how should they be represented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favourite approach to repeated line-based parsing is to use `std::getline` as the condition of a `while` loop and then parse the line inside:

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(input_stream, line)) {
  std::istringstream line_stream(line);
  // Parse the line by extracting from line_stream
}
```

It ensures that you have a whole line before you start parsing. This way, if something in the parsing of a single line goes wrong, it will still move on to the next line to continue.

For exapmle, I would perform the check of the fields that begin with a `#` like so:

```
int value;
if (line_stream.get() == '#' &&
    line_stream >> value &&
    std::isspace(line_stream.peek())) {
  // Success
}
```

My approach is to always put my extractions in some condition. This means you catch problems with the format as soon as possible.

Comment: How can you check that a line doesn't end prematurely?

Comment: @BobJohn Well then one of your extractions will fail and so a condition will evaluate to `false`. You don't even need a special check for premature ending.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that I have to check if my extraction fails after every extraction, then?  Like: line_stream >> value; if(value.fail())

Comment: @BobJohn No. See how I've done it in the `#` example. The extractions are *in* the condition. Extractions return the stream itself which is convertible to `bool` so you can check it's fail state. Just separate your extractions with `&&` and everything will work out great.

Comment: So after that if conditional, value will hold what's after #, without explicitly telling it in the if: line_stream >> value?

Comment: @BobJohn I don't understand. First `line_stream.get()` will extract a single character and check if it's a `#`. If it is, then `line_stream >> value` will extract an `int`. If that doesn't fail, `line_stream.peek()` will peek at the next character and see if it's a space.